# What are the set cli commands to stake on a validator node?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-api-client

[In this video Joe Petrowski](https://youtu.be/ejgPSwdLj5o?t=1130) demonstrates a command which allows us to set a stake and also choose a reward destination. But unfortunately some of the command gets obscured by their video picture.

As I've narrowed it down, I require a step-by-step procedure that shows us

- How to use polkadot-api-cli to sign and submit a session key (set session keys)
- The command for how to set validator prefernces i.e call staking.validate/chill

Edit #1 : I may have figured out how to set validator prefs: I get a json response with :
`yarn run:api  --seed .. tx.staking.validate '["30", false]' --ws ..`

However, I don't see a commission set to 30%. I've tried it with `30` and `"30"` both. I've also tried putting the second arg `"No"` instead of false and both seemed to work. However I'd like to set the commission % properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's the answer:
To validate using `polkadot-cli-api` you need three things:

1. Create a controller/stash pair and then tell your chain that they are a controller/stash pair using `staking.bond`
2. State your intention to validate
3. Generate session keys and insert them into your keystore.

You can use `signer` also, but I'll write for `api`.

`--ws` will take in the websocket address of your node for example `--ws "ws://127.0.0.1:9944"`

`--seed` will take the `seed` used to sign the transaction

1. api --account <Stash account> --seed <stash seed> --ws <ws endpoint> tx.staking.bond <Controller bs58 address> <Amount to bond> <Payee destination>
2. api --account <Controller account> --seed <controller seed> --ws <ws endpoint> tx.staking.validate '[<Commission in parts per billion>, <boolean to allow for nominations>]'
3. api --account <Controller> --seed ... --ws .... tx.session.setKeys <Input from author_rotateKeys()> 0x

If you follow these steps you'll be able to validate without access to a GUI.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you figured it out! I haven't used that CLI in a while.

And you mentioned it in the details, but commission is a `PerBill`. So 30% would be `300_000_000`.

Comment: Yes indeed. I had trouble with it when I gave a % instead of a Perbill.