# Staking: How to build the staking payload and send transaction?

Tags: staking

I want to achieve three functions but I do not know how to build the staking payload and send transaction,

The three functions are these:
The one is becoming a nominator and staking my amount;
The two is appending the staking my amount;
The three is unbounding my staking amount;

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question, and remove the unnecessary code-block formatting? This is hardly readable.

Comment: ok,please look up

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/q/1871/139 Should help you out using the polkadot js api client.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to familiarize yourself with the following resources:

- [Transactions](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx) – how to submit extrinsics from polkadot.js,
- [Complex transactions](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx.wrap) – a bit more about the above,
- [extrinsics#staking](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#staking) – full documentation of the extrinsics from the staking pallet.

Regarding the three 'functions' you want to achieve, I believe it should be done the following way:

1. "becoming a nominator and staking my amount" -> `api.tx.staking.bond(..)` and then `api.tx.staking.nominate(..)`,
2. "appending the staking my amount" -> `api.tx.staking.bondExtra(..)`,
3. "unbounding my staking amount" -> `api.tx.staking.unbound(..)` and the `api.tx.staking.withdrawUnbounded(..)`

Regarding the "staking payload" I don't really know what that means and if it's necessary.